# can we do validation or save entered field as full caps while saving the record

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have a situation where i am querying  using value entered in the record. if the value entered in the field is small letters and the ones in the objects are caps then the result is not correct as they are case sensitive.

Is there a way i can have the values entered all in caps? I know i can write a trigger to do it. Is there something in admin which would force this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a Salesforce page you can either create a formula for the field being saved from the SETUP menu on the object you are saving to.

Or you could create a workflow that would change the case to upper-case on new and update.

If you are using a Visualforce page, you can create a Before trigger and set the test to string.touppercase like Jeremy Ross has suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Are you querying using Apex? If so, do `String.toUpperCase()` on the search terms.